# WPF StackPanel.Resources setter on more than one control type?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to use a setter to set a default margin of all elements in my stackpanel, not just buttons but also textboxes and labels.

```
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        ...
```

When I try to change above Button to `Control` or `FrameworkElement` (a derived type of each element) it doesn't work.

How can I fix this without having to specify 2 different `Style` elements with the same content but different x:Types on the TargetType?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with inheritance via Style's [BasedOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) attribute:

```
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />

        </StackPanel.Resources>
```